# cv2 get information about the zoomed section when using `cv2.imshow()`

Tags: python, opencv

is there a way to get information about the zoomed section in python cv2 ?

when using opencv in python (`import cv2`)
then using `cv2.imshow('windowname', imgnparray)`
then when i hover over the image and use the scroll wheel i can zoom into the image, in python can i somehow get information about the zoomed area?

in my example the zoom would be around 3 times zoomed in and 0.5 offset left and 0.25 offset top

[image: zoomed_section]

Comment: as I know this window doesn't have method to get zoomed area. It has only method to assign function which will be executed when you move mouse and click button - so you can get some position/region on image. There is also function `ROI` to select `Region Of Interest`. [Capturing mouse click events with Python and OpenCV - PyImageSearch](https://pyimagesearch.com/2015/03/09/capturing-mouse-click-events-with-python-and-opencv/) and [How to select a bounding box ( ROI ) in OpenCV (C++/Python) ? | LearnOpenCV #](https://learnopencv.com/how-to-select-a-bounding-box-roi-in-opencv-cpp-python/)

Answer (score 2):

That's currently not possible.

To get this information, you would need to modify OpenCV's source code. You could open an issue about this, requesting the feature.

The relevant values can be found in the variable `positionCorners` in the file `modules/highgui/src/window_QT.cpp`.